# describe_replication_tasks filter on 'cdc' migration-type

Tags: boto3, aws-dms

I'm trying to use boto3 to filter replication tasks by cdc migration-type.  However, I cannot seem to find or guess correctly the different possible string Values.  Does anyone know what they are or where I can find them?

```
migration_type_filter = { 'Name': 'migration-type', 'Values': 'cdc' }
tasks = boto3.client('dms').describe_replication_tasks(Filters=[migration_type_filter])
```

Error:  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Filters[0].Values, value: cdc, type: , valid types: , "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'cdc' works.  I had the wrong syntax for the filter.

wrong:  migration_type_filter = { 'Name': 'migration-type', 'Values': 'cdc' }

correct: migration_type_filter = { 'Name': 'migration-type', 'Values': **[**'cdc'**]** }

Answer (score 0):

'MigrationType': 'full-load'|'cdc'|'full-load-and-cdc'

Comment: migration_type_filter = { 'Name': 'migration-type', 'Values': 'cdc' }

tasks = boto3.client('dms').describe_replication_tasks(Filters=[migration_type_filter])

Error:  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Filters[0].Values, value: cdc, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>"